# Updating of my record is not working

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am almost close to complete my project but I have two issues which may be unable to fix please can anyone guide me, I really need help. The issue I am facing is that when I try to update  "first name" or "last name" then I am getting an error, and the image path saved in the database is getting deleted. But if I try to update my image then it`s working fine. The second issue is that when I try to update my image the old image is not getting replaced with the new one, even the old image is avaliable in the folder. How to solve this two issues please I really need help .

From.php (controller part)

```
public function updatedata()
{
    $id=$this->input->get('id');
    $result['data']=$this->Form_model->displayrecordsById($id);

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('fname', 'First name', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('lname', 'Last name', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required|min_length[5]|max_length[12]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|valid_email');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
    {
        $this->load->view('update_records',$result);
    } else {
        $config['upload_path']   = './uploads/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        $fn=$this->input->post('fname');
        $ln=$this->input->post('lname');
        $un=$this->input->post('username');
        $em=$this->input->post('email');
        if($this->upload->do_upload('filename'))
        {
            $fi= $this->upload->data('file_name');
            $unlink = unlink('uploads/' . $row->filename);
        } else {
            $fi= $result['data']->filename;
        }
        $this->Form_model->updaterecords($fn,$ln,$un,$em,$fi,$id);
        echo 'Successfully updated your record';
        //exit();
    } 
}
```

Comment: Where do you define `$row`?

Comment: $row->filename from where it is coming..i didn't find anywhere $row from your function

Comment: from database im fetching is it correct?

Comment: NO..You need to define somewhere in your function first you need to retrieve the filename  from db and pass it there

Comment: how you  are getting the firstname and last name by using ID the same way you have to get the filename for the prticular ID

Comment: I'm getting it from result[data]

Comment: ok try to get the filename by using that variable name

Comment: the old image isn't being replaced by your code it is being deleted as the filenames should be different. is this desired?

Comment: Sir if I update the image then the updated image should be replaced with the exciting image. Please help me sir what changes I should do

Comment: I mean to say the old image should be unlinked and new image should be uploaded in the upload folder

Comment: why you are unlinking that let it be just update new image in the place of old image..when you are retrieving your image from db just call that image name from uploads folder

Comment: ofcourse it will delete because you are unlinking that..

Comment: @user200 assuming its because files can have different names as he hasn't specified a filename dependent on the circumstance. thus reducing orphans

Comment: if we have same files name then by that case we need to unlink that orelse we don't need to unlink right

Comment: i believe that is the general idea yea. but given that i don't see any name specifying code we can't assume that file names will be the same thus we should always delete the previous one

Comment: okay alex thats fine

Comment: when i try to update my records without making any changes to the image part then the images name from database is getting deleted, which means that im not getting the filename from the previously uploaded image which alternatively means the file name is not getting retrived like first name and last is getting retrived na in the same way it should get retrived na ? but its not getting retrived. i think if this gets fixed alternatively our task gets completed i guess, im trying n number of ways but not succeding in it please help me guys

Answer (score 0):

The first obvious issue is that `$row` var doesn't exist. In context it should be `$result['data']->filename`. And for your first question I don't see how updating fname and lname would logically lead to the *previously uploaded* file getting deleted unless another image is uploaded as `do_upload` will fail if no file is uploaded and thus enter your else statement.

Here I rearranged some things and added `encrypt_filename`. The primary purpose of this is to avoid issues where a user upload an image with the same name as a previously uploaded image even though the images might be different.

```
public function updatedata() {
        $id = $this->input->get('id');
        if (is_null($id)) {
            show_error('Id cannot be empty');
        }
        $result['data'] = $this->Form_model->displayrecordsById($id);
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('fname', 'First name', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('lname', 'Last name', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required|min_length[5]|max_length[12]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|valid_email');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
            $this->load->view('update_records', $result);

        } else {

            $config['encrypt_name'] = true; // highly recommended
            $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
            $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
            $this->load->library('upload', $config);

            $fi = $result['data']->filename;

            if ($this->upload->do_upload('filename')) {
                if (is_file('./uploads/' . $fi)) {
                    @unlink('./uploads/' . $fi);
                }
                $fi = $this->upload->data('file_name'); // set var to new name
            }

            $fn = $this->input->post('fname');
            $ln = $this->input->post('lname');
            $un = $this->input->post('username');
            $em = $this->input->post('email');

            $this->Form_model->updaterecords($fn, $ln, $un, $em, $fi, $id);
            echo 'Successfully updated your record';

        }
    }
```